# Clang only generating dll and no lib file

Tags: c, clang

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6_WdnzQIQ4&list=PLv8Ddw9K0JPg1BEO-RS-0MYs423cvLVtj&index=4 but when I run build-all.bat, clang only outputs a file called engine.dll into bin but no .lib or anything else.

This is the .bat file used to compile the engine

```
REM Build script for engine
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Get a list of all the .c files.
SET cFilenames=
FOR /R %%f in (*.c) do (
    SET cFilenames=!cFilenames! %%f
)

REM echo "Files:" %cFilenames%

SET assembly=engine
SET compilerFlags=-g -shared -Wvarargs -Wall -Werror
REM -Wall -Werror
SET includeFlags=-Isrc -I%VULKAN_SDK%/Include
SET linkerFlags=-luser32 -lvulkan-1 -L%VULKAN_SDK%/Lib
SET defines=-D_DEBUG -DKEXPORT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

ECHO "Building %assembly%%..."
clang %cFilenames% %compilerFlags% -o ../bin/%assembly%.dll %defines% %includeFlags% %linkerFlags%
```

Comment: You have `-o ../bin/%assembly%.dll` in the `clang` command. Why should it output anything other than that file?

Comment: @Barmar That's what I'm wondering. It used to output a .lib file and some other debugging stuff until I reinstalled clang. Now it doesn't